# A symbol above a comma

Tags: math-mode, symbols

How can I put a symbol above a comma? For example in

[image: figure]

Comment: Old [so] question: [How to put a symbol above another in LaTeX?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3098680/914686)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `\overset` from amsmath:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[\{L(\lambda)\ \overset{\otimes}{,}\ L(\mu)\}\]
\end{document}
```

I added optional spaces to make it look more like your example:

[image]

As noted in the comment, you can use `\scriptscriptstyle` to make `\otimes` smaller:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[\{L(\lambda)\ \overset{\scriptscriptstyle\otimes}{,}\ L(\mu)\}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You shouldn’t use spaces like that, but wrap the symbol in `\mathbin` or `\mathpunct` depending on the desired interpretation to get proper spacing.

Answer (score 13):

The following example sets `\otimes` as upper limit over the comma, which is turned to a math operator via `\mathop`. This also decreases the size of ⊗. By explicitly using `\scriptscriptstyle`, the symbol can be decreased further, see Manuel's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237770/a-symbol-above-a-comma/237775?noredirect=1#comment564140_237775).
Then the result is wrapped in `\mathpunct` to keep the property of the comma as punctuation character:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\commaotimes}{%
  \mathpunct{%
    \mathop{,}\limits^{\otimes}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\commaotimessmall}{%
  \mathpunct{%
    \mathop{,}\limits^{\scriptscriptstyle\otimes}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\[ \{ L(\lambda) \commaotimes L(\mu) \} \]
\[ \{ L(\lambda) \commaotimessmall L(\mu) \} \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remark:**

- The symbol `\commatimessmall` works well in math styles `\displaystyle` and `\textstyle`. For `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle` the symbol `\otimes` does not change it size, because there is no `\scriptscriptscriptstyle`.

Comment: I think it' `\scripscriptstyle` (which also looks better, in my opinion).

Comment: keeping the `\mathpunct` property leaves more space after the compound than before.  is that desired?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I have understood the symbol from the question as annotated comma. Therefore I have added `\mathpunct` to the the normal spacing of a comma with more space after the symbol. But `\mathpunct` can be easily replaced by `\mathbin` or `\mathrel` to change the spacing behavior of the symbol.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility `\stackrel{\otimes}{,}`:

```
$\left\{L\left(\lambda\right)\ \stackrel{\otimes}{,}\ L\left(\mu\right)\right\}$
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you should use a `\raisebox`