# How to make an arrow with words on top in texstudio

Tags: arrows

I am new in TeXstudio editor and I want to add an arrow with words above to show a transition 
between two states. Something like the picture below.

[image]

How can I do that.

Comment: see this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237770/a-symbol-above-a-comma

Answer (score 2):

You could use mathtools.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
     $\xrightarrow{print(5)}$
\end{document}
```